# Table width with ctable

Tags: width, ctable

i'm having a problem with the width of a table in my thesis. Its my first document with Latex.

I have two tables.
First table:

```
\ctable[
caption = {Comparison between $K_D$ values in \citet{SPM_1977} and \citet{SPM_1984} for structure trunk },
label = {tab:KD_SPM_trunk},
mincapwidth = \textwidth,
width = \textwidth,
]{Xcccccc}{
  \tnote[a]{Applicable to slopes ranging from 1:1.5 to 1:5;}
  \tnote[b]{These $K_D$ values are unsupported by test results and are only provided for preliminary design purposes;}
  \tnote[c]{Refers to no-damage criteria (<5\% displacement, rocking, etc.); if no rocking (<2\%) is desired, reduce KD by 50 percent \citep{Zwamborn_1982};}
  \tnote[d]{The use of a single layer of quarrystone armor units is not recommended for structures subject to breaking waves and only under special conditions for structures subject to nonbreaking waves. When used, the stone should be carefully placed;}
  \tnote[e]{Special placement with long axis of stone placed perpendicular to structure face;}
  \tnote[f]{Parallelepiped-shaped stone: long slab-like stone with the long dimension about 3 times the shortest dimension \citep{Markle_1979}.}
}{ \\
    \toprule
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Armor Units} & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{n} & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Placement} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Structure Trunk\tmark[a]} \\
          &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SPM 1977} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SPM 1984} \\
          &       &       & Breaking & Nonbreaking & Breaking & Nonbreaking \\
              \midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Quarrystone}} &       &       &       &  \\
    Smooth Rounded & 2     & Random & 2.1   & 2.4   & 1.2\tmark[b]  & 2.4 \\
    Smooth Rounded & >3    & Random & 2.8   & 3.2   & 1.6\tmark[b]  & 3.2\tmark[b] \\
    Rough Angular & 1\tmark[d]    & Random & -     & 2.9   & -     & 2.9\tmark[b] \\
    \multirow{3}[2]{*}{Rough Angular} & \multirow{3}[2]{*}{2} & \multirow{3}[2]{*}{Random} & \multirow{3}[2]{*}{3.5} & \multirow{3}[2]{*}{4.0} & \multirow{3}[2]{*}{2.0} & \multirow{3}[2]{*}{4.0} \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    Rough Angular & >3    & Random & 3.9   & 4.5   & 2.2\tmark[b]  & 4.5\tmark[b] \\
    Rough Angular & 2     & Speciale & 4.8   & 5.5   & 5.8   & 7.0 \\
    Parallelepiped\tmark[f] & 2     & Special & -     & -     & 7.0 - 20.0 & 8.5 - 24.0\tmark[b] \\
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Concrete armor units}} &       &       &       &  \\
    Tetrapod and Quadripod & 2     & Random & 7.2   & 8.3   & 7.0   & 8.0 \\
    Tribar & 2     & Random & 9.0   & 10.4  & 9.0\tmark[b]  & 10.0 \\
    Dolos & 2     & Random & 22.0\tmark[c] & 25.0\tmark[c] & 15.8\tmark[c] & 31.8\tmark[c] \\
    Modified Cube & 2     & Random & 6.8   & 7.8   & 6.5\tmark[b]  & 7.5 \\
    Hexapod & 2     & Random & 8.2   & 9.5   & 8.0\tmark[b]  & 9.5 \\
    Toskane & 2     & Random & -     & -     & 11.0\tmark[b] & 22.0 \\
    Tribar & 1     & Uniform & 12.0  & 15.0  & 12.0\tmark[b] & 15.0 \\
    \bottomrule
}
```

[image]

Second table:

```
\ctable[
caption = {Comparison between $K_D$ values in \citet{SPM_1977} and \citet{SPM_1984} for structure head },
label = {tab:KD_SPM_head},
mincapwidth = \textwidth,
width = \textwidth,
]{Xccccccc}{
  \tnote[a]{These $K_D$ values are unsupported by test results and are only provided for preliminary design purposes;}
  \tnote[b]{Stability of dolosse on slopes steeper than 1:2 should be substantiated by site-specific model test;}
  \tnote[c]{Until more information is available on the variation of $K_D$ value with slope, the use of $K_D$ should be limited to slopes raging from 1:1.5 to 1:3. Some armor units tested on a structure head indicate a $K_D$-slope dependence;}
  \tnote[d]{The use of a single layer of quarrystone armor units is not recommended for structures subject to breaking waves and only under special conditions for structures subject to nonbreaking waves. When used, the stone should be carefully placed;}
  \tnote[e]{Special placement with long axis of stone placed perpendicular to structure face;}
  \tnote[f]{Cotagent of the slope angle that the structure wall makes with the horizontal.}
}{ \\
    \toprule
     \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Armor Units} & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{n} & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Placement} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Structure Head} \\
          &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SPM 1977} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SPM 1984} & Slope \\
          &       &       & Breaking & Nonbreaking & Breaking & Nonbreaking & cot  \\
                  \midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Quarrystone}} &       &       &       &       &  \\
    Smooth Rounded & 2     & Random & 1.7   & 1.9   & 1.1\tmark[a]  & 1.9   & 1.5 to 3.0 \\
    Smooth Rounded & >3    & Random & 2.1   & 2.3   & 1.4\tmark[a]  & 2.3\tmark[a]  & c \\
    Rough Angular & 1\tmark[d]    & Random & -     & 2.3   & -     & 2.3\tmark[a]  & \tmark[c] \\
    \cmidrule(rl){4-8}
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Rough Angular} & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{2} & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Random} & 2.9   & 3.2   & 1.9\tmark[a]  & 3.2   & 1.5 \\
          &       &       & 2.5   & 2.8   & 1.6\tmark[a]  & 2.8   & 2.0 \\
          &       &       & 2.0   & 2.3   & 1.3   & 2.3   & 3.0 \\
          \cmidrule(rl){4-8}
    Rough Angular & >3    & Random & 3.7   & 4.2   & 2.1\tmark[a]  & 4.2\tmark[a]  & c\tmark[c] \\
    Rough Angular & 2     & Special\tmark[e] & 3.5   & 4.5   & 5.3\tmark[a]  & 6.4\tmark[a]  & \tmark[c] \\
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Concrete armor units}} &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \cmidrule(rl){4-8}
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Tetrapod and Quadripod} & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{2} & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Random} & 5.9   & 6.6   & 5.0\tmark[a]  & 6.0   & 1.5 \\
          &       &       & 5.5   & 6.1   & 4.5\tmark[a]  & 5.5   & 2.0 \\
          &       &       & 3.7   & 4.1   & 3.5\tmark[a]  & 4.0   & 3.0 \\
          \cmidrule(rl){4-8}
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Tribar} & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{2} & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Random} & 8.3   & 9.0   & 8.3\tmark[a]  & 9.0   & 1.5 \\
          &       &       & 7.8   & 8.5   & 7.8\tmark[a]  & 8.5   & 2.0 \\
          &       &       & 7.0   & 7.7   & 6.0\tmark[a]  & 6.5   & 3.0 \\
          \cmidrule(rl){4-8}
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Dolos} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{2} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Random} & 15.0  & 16.5  & 8.0\tmark[a]  & 16.0\tmark[a] & 2.0\tmark[b] \\
          &       &       & 13.5  & 15.0  & 7.0\tmark[a]  & 14.0\tmark[a] & 3.0 \\
    Modified Cube & 2     & Random & -     & 5.0   & -     & 5.0   & \tmark[c] \\
    Hexapod & 2     & Random & 5.0   & 7.0   & 5.0   & 7.0   & \tmark[c] \\
    Tribar & 1     & Uniform & 7.5   & 9.5   & 7.5   & 9.5   & \tmark[c] \\
    \bottomrule
}
```

[image]

As seen on figure 2, the table is too wide because I use {ccccccc} instead of {Xcccccc} in the definition. If I use {Xcccccc} in the definition of this second table this happens:
[image]

Can someone help me formatting this table?

Best reggards,
Diogo Silva

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your snippet is useful, but it would be ideal if you could turn it into a complete Minimum Working Example :) If you're not sure how to create one, have a look at [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) for reference - welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your table is too wide to fit on the page so `ctable` needs to squash the columns together in order to make the table the required width. If you change the width of the table to, say, `150mm` then the first and second columns will stop overlapping.

[image]

Perhaps a better option is to try and shorten or abbreviate some of your column headings. An obvious heading to pick on is `Nonbreaking`:

[image]

I am not suggesting that `Non` is a good abbreviation for `Nonbreaking` but instead showing that this is one way to fix your problem -- and I think that some variation on this will be your best solution.

This was done using the following hack of your table. Note that I also changed your naked > signs into `$>$` and I took your `\multirow`'s out of the first column as they were stopping the `X` column specifier from working. This probably is still not quite what you want but hopefully it is a step in the right direction.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ctable,multirow}
\usepackage[sort&compress,square,comma,authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}

\ctable[
caption = {Comparison between $K_D$ values in \citet{SPM_1977} and \citet{SPM_1984} for structure head\hss },
label = {tab:KD_SPM_head},
mincapwidth = \textwidth,
width = \textwidth,
]{@{}Xccccccc}{
  \tnote[a]{These $K_D$ values are unsupported by test results and are only provided for preliminary design purposes;}
  \tnote[b]{Stability of dolosse on slopes steeper than 1:2 should be substantiated by site-specific model test;}
  \tnote[c]{Until more information is available on the variation of $K_D$ value with slope, the use of $K_D$ should be limited to slopes raging from 1:1.5 to 1:3. Some armor units tested on a structure head indicate a $K_D$-slope dependence;}
  \tnote[d]{The use of a single layer of quarrystone armor units is not recommended for structures subject to breaking waves and only under special conditions for structures subject to nonbreaking waves. When used, the stone should be carefully placed;}
  \tnote[e]{Special placement with long axis of stone placed perpendicular to structure face;}
  \tnote[f]{Cotagent of the slope angle that the structure wall makes with the horizontal.}
}{ \\
    \toprule
     \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Armor Units} & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{n} & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Placement} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Structure Head} \\
          &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SPM 1977} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SPM 1984} & Slope \\
          &       &       & Breaking & Non& Breaking & Non& cot  \\
                  \midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Quarrystone}} &       &       &       &       &  \\
    Smooth Rounded & 2     & Random & 1.7   & 1.9   & 1.1\tmark[a]  & 1.9   & 1.5 -- 3.0 \\
    Smooth Rounded & ${>}3$    & Random & 2.1   & 2.3   & 1.4\tmark[a]  & 2.3\tmark[a]  & c \\
    Rough Angular & 1\tmark[d]    & Random & -     & 2.3   & -     & 2.3\tmark[a]  & \tmark[c] \\
    \cmidrule(rl){4-8}
    Rough Angular & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{2} & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Random} & 2.9   & 3.2   & 1.9\tmark[a]  & 3.2   & 1.5 \\
          &       &       & 2.5   & 2.8   & 1.6\tmark[a]  & 2.8   & 2.0 \\
          &       &       & 2.0   & 2.3   & 1.3   & 2.3   & 3.0 \\
          \cmidrule(rl){4-8}
          Rough Angular &${>}3$   & Random & 3.7   & 4.2   & 2.1\tmark[a]  & 4.2\tmark[a]  & c\tmark[c] \\
    Rough Angular & 2     & Special\tmark[e] & 3.5   & 4.5   & 5.3\tmark[a]  & 6.4\tmark[a]  & \tmark[c] \\
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Concrete armor units}} &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \cmidrule(rl){4-8}
    Tetrapod& \multirow{3}[6]{*}{2} & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Random} & 5.9   & 6.6   & 5.0\tmark[a]  & 6.0   & 1.5 \\
    and   &       &       & 5.5   & 6.1   & 4.5\tmark[a]  & 5.5   & 2.0 \\
   Quradripod&       &       & 3.7   & 4.1   & 3.5\tmark[a]  & 4.0   & 3.0 \\
          \cmidrule(rl){4-8}
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Tribar} & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{2} & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Random} & 8.3   & 9.0   & 8.3\tmark[a]  & 9.0   & 1.5 \\
          &       &       & 7.8   & 8.5   & 7.8\tmark[a]  & 8.5   & 2.0 \\
          &       &       & 7.0   & 7.7   & 6.0\tmark[a]  & 6.5   & 3.0 \\
          \cmidrule(rl){4-8}
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Dolos} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{2} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Random} & 15.0  & 16.5  & 8.0\tmark[a]  & 16.0\tmark[a] & 2.0\tmark[b] \\
          &       &       & 13.5  & 15.0  & 7.0\tmark[a]  & 14.0\tmark[a] & 3.0 \\
    Modified Cube & 2     & Random & -     & 5.0   & -     & 5.0   & \tmark[c] \\
    Hexapod & 2     & Random & 5.0   & 7.0   & 5.0   & 7.0   & \tmark[c] \\
    Tribar & 1     & Uniform & 7.5   & 9.5   & 7.5   & 9.5   & \tmark[c] \\
    \bottomrule
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Didn't know that multi row affected the specifier, now it works great. Thank you for the help